# Ajax request, null data, path to the server rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

I have a client request with Ajax, the final url is `/promotion?mtd`, the log tell me that parameter mtd = null. It should be promo = mtd, i need the data I am passing in the url.

AJAX:

```
var promo = document.getElementById('data-select').value;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/promotion',
        data: promo,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data){
          alert(data);
        }
    });
```

log/development.log:

```
Started GET "/promotion?mtd" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-14 16:32:34 -0430
Processing by PromosController#get_percent as JSON
  Parameters: {"mtd"=>nil}
```

Comment: data: {"mtd": promo},

Comment: promo get the value of `data-select`, mtd is the value of the dropdown selected @vinayakj

Comment: didnt get you. what param do you want to read at backend?

Comment: I didn't know I have to pass in `data` the parameter @vinayakj

Comment: yes you need to send the key so that backend can pickup the value by key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var promo = document.getElementById('data-select').value;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/promotion',
        data: {"promo" : promo},
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data){
          alert(data);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Work with `data: { promo : promo}`. Thanks!